# How to remove download URL option from all files in firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I know on the Firebase storage console, you can disable the access token for a specific file. Is there a way to programmatically disable them for files uploaded to the platform? This seems like a pretty useful feature for files that you only want to allow access to within the app.